# Undertow access logs to multiple destinations (file, stdout, etc)

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, logging, undertow

I am trying to configure Access logs in springboot application, i have enabled access logs to be sent to a file using this configuration in accesslog.properties file

```
server.undertow.accesslog.enabled=true
server.undertow.accesslog.pattern=%t %a "%r" %s (%D ms)
```

I want to additionally log to console meaning access logs should go to both file and to stdout at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the logs in the console by using the internal logs of the undertow server

logging.level.io.undertow.server=DEBUG

logging.level.io.undertow.websockets=DEBUG

Comment: I want the access logs to be sent to two destinations, i already have them getting sent to the file, i am using .properties file, i just want them to be sent to stdout.

`# configuration for file`
`server.undertow.accesslog.dir=${path}/`
`server.undertow.accesslog.prefix=access`
`server.undertow.accesslog.suffix=log`

`# Configuration for console`
`server.undertow.accesslog.dir=/dev`
`server.undertow.accesslog.prefix=stdout`
`server.undertow.accesslog.suffix=`
Problem is this will only consider 1 property either send it to the file or to the console. i am not sure how your ans helps

Comment: Questions seems to be related to accesslogs specifically and not the level of logging server.